# Sim800L does not send SMS messages in a row

Tags: sms

I created a project with sim800l that comes and stores 5 phone numbers in eeprom memory and then when a sensor is triggered, it sms all the numbers and then calls the first one.
But the module does not send an SMS to everyone and only sends an SMS to the first number and then nothing else and then calls. The problem is not that the numbers are not read correctly, because when sending the text message, I said, show the number in the monitor series and it will show correctly. It is not a problem not to send a text message request because I also connected a usb to ttl module to the tx rx module and saw that it comes for all numbers and at sends the at command correctly.

```
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define SIM800RX 7 //D7 - SIM800L RX PIN
#define SIM800TX 8 //D8 - SIM800L TX PIN

#define SENSOR1SMSTEXT "Fire error" //Sensor 1 SMS Text
#define SENSOR2SMSTEXT "Theft error" //Sensor 2 SMS Text

SoftwareSerial SIM800(SIM800RX, SIM800TX);

String readSerial(String txt) {
  SIM800.flush();
  if (SIM800.readString() != "") {
    while (SIM800.readString() != "") {}
  }
  String text = "";
  if (txt != "") {
    SIM800.println(txt);
    int timeout = 0;
    while  (!SIM800.available() && timeout < 12000) {
      delay(1);
      timeout++;
    }
    if (SIM800.available()) {
      text = SIM800.readString();
    }
  }
  return text;
}

void readSerialOK(String txt) {
  while (readSerial(txt).indexOf("OK") == -1) {
    delay(700);
  }
}

void configSim800L() {
  readSerialOK("AT");
  delay(200);
  readSerialOK("AT+CMGF=1");
  delay(200);
  readSerialOK("AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0");
  delay(200);
  readSerialOK("AT+CMGDA=\"DEL ALL\"");
  delay(200);
  readSerialOK("AT+CSMP=17,167,0,0");
  delay(200);
}

void SendTextSMS(String num, String sms) {
  SIM800.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
  SIM800.print(num);
  SIM800.println("\"");
  delay(150);
  SIM800.print(sms);
  SIM800.write(26);
  delay(700);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Send SMS to:");
  Serial.print(num);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.println(sms);
}

bool checkPhone(String phone) {
  if (phone.substring(0, 2) == "09" && phone.length() == 11) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

void WriteEEPROM(byte part, String val) {
  int start_addw = part * 16;
  int w_len = val.length();
  EEPROM.write(start_addw, w_len + 1);
  int end_w = start_addw + w_len;
  byte len = 0;
  for (int i = start_addw + 1; i < end_w + 1; i++) {
    EEPROM.write(i, int(val[len]));
    len++;
  }
  len = 0;
  EEPROM.commit();
}

String ReadEEPROM(byte part) {
  int start_addr = part * 16;
  String str;
  int ch;
  int r_len = EEPROM.read(start_addr);
  int end_r = start_addr + r_len;
  for (int i = start_addr + 1; i < end_r; i++) {
    ch = EEPROM.read(i);
    str += char(ch);
  }
  if (checkPhone(str) == false) {
    str = "";
  }
  return str;
}

void ClearEEPROM(byte part) {
  int start_addw = part * 16;
  int w_len = 11;
  EEPROM.write(start_addw, 0);
  int end_w = start_addw + w_len;
  byte len = 0;
  for (int i = start_addw + 1; i < end_w + 1; i++) {
    EEPROM.write(i, 0);
    len++;
  }
  len = 0;
  EEPROM.commit();
}

void SendSMS(String sms) {
  String num1 = ReadEEPROM(1);
  String num2 = ReadEEPROM(2);
  String num3 = ReadEEPROM(3);
  String num4 = ReadEEPROM(4);
  String num5 = ReadEEPROM(5);
  if (num1 != "") {
    SendTextSMS(num1, sms);
  }
  if (num2 != "") {
    SendTextSMS(num2, sms);
  }
  if (num3 != "") {
    SendTextSMS(num3, sms);
  }
  if (num4 != "") {
    SendTextSMS(num4, sms);
  }
  if (num5 != "") {
    SendTextSMS(num5, sms);
  }
}

void Call() {
  String call = "";
  String num1 = ReadEEPROM(1);
  String num2 = ReadEEPROM(2);
  String num3 = ReadEEPROM(3);
  String num4 = ReadEEPROM(4);
  String num5 = ReadEEPROM(5);
  if (num1 != "") {
    call = num1;
  } else if (num2 != "") {
    call = num2;
  } else if (num3 != "") {
    call = num3;
  } else if (num4 != "") {
    call = num4;
  } else if (num5 != "") {
    call = num5;
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Call to:");
  Serial.print(call);
  if (call != "") {
    readSerialOK("ATD"+call+";");
    delay(300);
  }
}


void trigSensor1() {
  SendSMS(SENSOR1SMSTEXT);
  Call();
}

void trigSensor2() {
  SendSMS(SENSOR2SMSTEXT);
  Call();
}

void setup() {
  SIM800.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  EEPROM.begin(512);
  pinMode(IN1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(IN2, INPUT);
  pinMode(SSS, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SSS, LOW);
  while (readSerial("AT+COPS?").indexOf("+COPS: 0,0,\"") == -1) {
    delay(700);
  }
  configSim800L();
  digitalWrite(SSS, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(IN1) == LOW) {
      trigSensor1();
  }
  if (digitalRead(IN2) == HIGH) {
      trigSensor2();
  }
}
```

Thanks if friends have experience in this area tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this exact problem and solution is repeated many times on the internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find error:

```
void SendTextSMS(String num, String sms) {
  SIM800.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
  SIM800.print(num);
  SIM800.println("\"");
  delay(150);
  SIM800.print(sms);
  SIM800.write(26);
  delay(3000);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Send SMS to:");
  Serial.print(num);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.println(sms);
}
```

i replaced delay with 3000ms the error solved.